# Proper git server setup for my system

Tags: node.js, git

Ok.  I know I am going to word this confusing and I apologize upfront.  This is what I am attempting to do:

1. I want to setup git on a webserver that I am hosting node.js apps
   on.
2. I want to be able to push to it from my other computers.
3. I want to be able to see the files on the server that get pushed.

The reason is because I would like to have something like *forever* running on the webserver (which happens to be NGINX, not that it matters) so that it will notice that the files have changed and reloads the node.js apps.  This is not the part that I need help with, I just wanted to be as thorough as possible.

Now for the question, can I setup a git repo on the server so that I can actually see the files?  I know that the server side is technically supposed to be bare, and as far as I know, that means I can't technically see the files, it's only used to store the information.

How would I go about setting this up or am I attempting to do something that is not possible?  I am just trying to avoid FTP or some other odd way, if I can do it with git push, pull, merge, etc.  Eventually, I was going to run a production branch & development branch on different ports and make them run simultaneously so that I could just merge the changes into production, without doing a lot of extra work.  Either way, I plan on using git.  I would just like to use it like I described.  :)

You can let me know if I am being ridiculous or whatever.  I am not very knowledgeable about git and am trying to better understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want to deploy the develop/production code automatically when someone push code to their branches?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I am the only Developer.  I am just trying to streamline the process without having to FTP.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In your production server,you need to do following:

Create a **project_contents** directory as following:

```
/opt/project_contents/
```

Create **project.git** directory as following:

```
/var/git/project.git/
```

Inside **project.git** directory,run following:

```
git init --bare
```

Now you need to tell git to run certain commands every time something is pushed to **project.git**.So create a file named **post-receive** in **/var/git/project.git/hooks/** directory.
The **post-receive** file contents can be something like following:

```
#!/bin/sh

git --work-tree=/opt/project_contents/ --git-dir=/var/git/project.git/ checkout -f
```

So every time a git push is done to this **project.git**,it would store the project contents in **/opt/project_contents/** directory. 
You might also want to automate installing node modules through this **post-receive** file.To do so,append the following lines to the **post-receive** file.

```
cd /opt/project_contents/server/
npm install
```

Make sure that post-receive file is executable.To do so,run :

```
chmod +x /var/git/project.git/hooks/post-receive
```

### Now in your local machine,you need to do following:

Add the prduction server's **project.git** directory as a git remote of your local git project directory using following command.

```
git remote add prod ssh://user_name@server_name/var/git/project.git
```

To push your current project to production server,run :

```
git push prod master
```

NOTE:

- Ensure that ssh key of your local machine is set up in prod server.

You can also refer to https://ma.ttias.be/simple-git-push-workflow-deploy-code-server/ for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is implement Continuous Integration/Deployment. Overall its very vast subject, but I can provide you some links which you read and figure it out.

1. [JENKINS](https://jenkins.io/)
2. [GOCD](https://www.gocd.org/)
3. [GITLAB CI](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/)

There are some other tools available too that you can find [here](https://www.code-maze.com/top-8-continuous-integration-tools/).

Good Luck, and Happy Integration!

Comment: Thank you for your help!